# Where is the default color / custom theme defined?

Tags: customize, themes, custom

When you start Emacs with `emacs -Q`, there appears to be some sort of default color scheme. Where are these colors defined? The default theme does not show up with `M-x customize`, nor can I find it in `etc/themes`. I have even tried taking a screenshot of the theme, figuring out the hex codes and doing `grep -r 'a020f0' .` and `grep -r 'b22222' .` inside the source tree, but I can't find anything.

Comment: `faces.el` has a few.  `font-lock.el` has a few.  `org-faces.el` has a few.  You can type `M-x find-face` or `M-x customize-face` or `M-x list-faces-display`.  The faces are spread out.  A custom theme merely has a few common faces that the theme author has hand selected.

Comment: You can also grep the Emacs source code for the word `defface`, which will give **900+** faces -- give or take a few :)

Answer (score 3):

Thanks lawlist for pointing me in the right direction.

I realize I was not being clear in my question. I was primarily concerned with finding the default *`font-lock`* faces. Found them in `font-lock.el`:

```
;;; Color etc. support.

;; Note that `defface' will not overwrite any faces declared above via
;; `custom-declare-face'.
(defface font-lock-comment-face
  '((((class grayscale) (background light))
     :foreground "DimGray" :weight bold :slant italic)
    (((class grayscale) (background dark))
     :foreground "LightGray" :weight bold :slant italic)
    (((class color) (min-colors 88) (background light))
     :foreground "Firebrick")
    (((class color) (min-colors 88) (background dark))
     :foreground "chocolate1")
    (((class color) (min-colors 16) (background light))
     :foreground "red")
    (((class color) (min-colors 16) (background dark))
     :foreground "red1")
    (((class color) (min-colors 8) (background light))
     :foreground "red")
    (((class color) (min-colors 8) (background dark))
     :foreground "yellow")
    (t :weight bold :slant italic))
  "Font Lock mode face used to highlight comments."
  :group 'font-lock-faces)

(defface font-lock-comment-delimiter-face
  '((default :inherit font-lock-comment-face))
  "Font Lock mode face used to highlight comment delimiters."
  :group 'font-lock-faces)

(defface font-lock-string-face
  '((((class grayscale) (background light)) :foreground "DimGray" :slant italic)
    (((class grayscale) (background dark))  :foreground "LightGray" :slant italic)
    (((class color) (min-colors 88) (background light)) :foreground "VioletRed4")
    (((class color) (min-colors 88) (background dark))  :foreground "LightSalmon")
    (((class color) (min-colors 16) (background light)) :foreground "RosyBrown")
    (((class color) (min-colors 16) (background dark))  :foreground "LightSalmon")
    (((class color) (min-colors 8)) :foreground "green")
    (t :slant italic))
  "Font Lock mode face used to highlight strings."
  :group 'font-lock-faces)

(defface font-lock-doc-face
  '((t :inherit font-lock-string-face))
  "Font Lock mode face used to highlight documentation."
  :group 'font-lock-faces)

(defface font-lock-keyword-face
  '((((class grayscale) (background light)) :foreground "LightGray" :weight bold)
    (((class grayscale) (background dark))  :foreground "DimGray" :weight bold)
    (((class color) (min-colors 88) (background light)) :foreground "Purple")
    (((class color) (min-colors 88) (background dark))  :foreground "Cyan1")
    (((class color) (min-colors 16) (background light)) :foreground "Purple")
    (((class color) (min-colors 16) (background dark))  :foreground "Cyan")
    (((class color) (min-colors 8)) :foreground "cyan" :weight bold)
    (t :weight bold))
  "Font Lock mode face used to highlight keywords."
  :group 'font-lock-faces)

(defface font-lock-builtin-face
  '((((class grayscale) (background light)) :foreground "LightGray" :weight bold)
    (((class grayscale) (background dark))  :foreground "DimGray" :weight bold)
    (((class color) (min-colors 88) (background light)) :foreground "dark slate blue")
    (((class color) (min-colors 88) (background dark))  :foreground "LightSteelBlue")
    (((class color) (min-colors 16) (background light)) :foreground "Orchid")
    (((class color) (min-colors 16) (background dark)) :foreground "LightSteelBlue")
    (((class color) (min-colors 8)) :foreground "blue" :weight bold)
    (t :weight bold))
  "Font Lock mode face used to highlight builtins."
  :group 'font-lock-faces)

(defface font-lock-function-name-face
  '((((class color) (min-colors 88) (background light)) :foreground "Blue1")
    (((class color) (min-colors 88) (background dark))  :foreground "LightSkyBlue")
    (((class color) (min-colors 16) (background light)) :foreground "Blue")
    (((class color) (min-colors 16) (background dark))  :foreground "LightSkyBlue")
    (((class color) (min-colors 8)) :foreground "blue" :weight bold)
    (t :inverse-video t :weight bold))
  "Font Lock mode face used to highlight function names."
  :group 'font-lock-faces)

(defface font-lock-variable-name-face
  '((((class grayscale) (background light))
     :foreground "Gray90" :weight bold :slant italic)
    (((class grayscale) (background dark))
     :foreground "DimGray" :weight bold :slant italic)
    (((class color) (min-colors 88) (background light)) :foreground "sienna")
    (((class color) (min-colors 88) (background dark))  :foreground "LightGoldenrod")
    (((class color) (min-colors 16) (background light)) :foreground "DarkGoldenrod")
    (((class color) (min-colors 16) (background dark))  :foreground "LightGoldenrod")
    (((class color) (min-colors 8)) :foreground "yellow" :weight light)
    (t :weight bold :slant italic))
  "Font Lock mode face used to highlight variable names."
  :group 'font-lock-faces)

(defface font-lock-type-face
  '((((class grayscale) (background light)) :foreground "Gray90" :weight bold)
    (((class grayscale) (background dark))  :foreground "DimGray" :weight bold)
    (((class color) (min-colors 88) (background light)) :foreground "ForestGreen")
    (((class color) (min-colors 88) (background dark))  :foreground "PaleGreen")
    (((class color) (min-colors 16) (background light)) :foreground "ForestGreen")
    (((class color) (min-colors 16) (background dark))  :foreground "PaleGreen")
    (((class color) (min-colors 8)) :foreground "green")
    (t :weight bold :underline t))
  "Font Lock mode face used to highlight type and classes."
  :group 'font-lock-faces)

(defface font-lock-constant-face
  '((((class grayscale) (background light))
     :foreground "LightGray" :weight bold :underline t)
    (((class grayscale) (background dark))
     :foreground "Gray50" :weight bold :underline t)
    (((class color) (min-colors 88) (background light)) :foreground "dark cyan")
    (((class color) (min-colors 88) (background dark))  :foreground "Aquamarine")
    (((class color) (min-colors 16) (background light)) :foreground "CadetBlue")
    (((class color) (min-colors 16) (background dark))  :foreground "Aquamarine")
    (((class color) (min-colors 8)) :foreground "magenta")
    (t :weight bold :underline t))
  "Font Lock mode face used to highlight constants and labels."
  :group 'font-lock-faces)
```

For a light background (also, another point I was vague on; I only really cared about the case of a light background), they are:

- Comment: Firebrick
- String: VioletRed4
- Keyword: Purple
- Builtin: dark slate blue
- Function name: Blue1
- Variable name: sienna
- Type: ForestGreen
- Constant: dark cyan